# Quadratic Congruence in $\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$

Tags: quadratics, parity

Given the congruence $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod {2^n}$, how precisely does one go about finding its roots?
I'm comfortable with quadratic congruence mod n with n odd, but 2's lack of a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$ complicates matters, and the standard parity root test doesn't generally provide much help.
I suppose in $\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$ we look for roots mod 2 and apply Hensel Lifting, etc., this no different than for powers of odd primes?

What I would really appreciate is a detailed description of what one does to analyze a quadratic in a mod ring of integers with parity.  To be honest I am surprised that  I can't find a satisfactory exposition of this — I'm wondering if I'm thinking about it all wrong.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hensel sounds good to me.

Comment: See the section in `Powers of 2` in http://www.johndcook.com/quadratic_congruences.html

Comment: @gammatester thank you for the suggestion, I've already been through that.  I may not know enough to know what I'm looking for, but it didn't strike me as being quite that.  I'm not just interested in quadratic residues (especially not with the gcd(a,m)=1 restriction) so much as the general approach to factoring order two elements of the ring of polynomials P[x] with coefficients in a ring P possessing parity.  In my simplified endeavors, P will always be of the form Z/(2n)Z.  But I'd be interested in the most general comments possible!